# string was not in a correct format (mysql + .net)

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

I have a datatype of varchar(200) in MySql, and when when I try to insert value '11111' it is OK. But when I try to insert '1111.1' it is showing this error

> Input string was not in correct format

Comment: Did you try inserting the value with single quotes '' ?

Comment: no i just passed the value in .NET as absItem.photo = "111111111.1";

Comment: You can't enter this value for varchar datatype. Change datatype to decimal.

Comment: the data is varchar because i am storing image name in it as 'photo.jpg'

Comment: Then how come '111111111.1'? Is it the image name?

Comment: I just Showed you an Example... any thing with dot it is not taking

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40624/discussion-between-aishvarya-and-nisar)

Comment: Post code to get help, This information is not sufficient to help you. Your table definition, code which inserts data etc